# How to process database writes asynchronously (maybe with a message queue) from Django?

Tags: database, django, error-handling, asynchronous, message-queue

After a user submitted data to my app, I'd like to write to the
database asynchronously, possibly through a message queue.

How do I set up such a system? Are there any pluggable Django apps
that do such message queue-based database writes?

Also how do i handle errors that happens during the async processing?

Would really appreciate any pointers you can give me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) as a queue mechanism with a processor on the back end. It's one of the simpler setups, and very effective. You can back it with persistence, or not, as you need. There's [a good walk through on setting it with django](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-django.html) up on the website as well. Typically you'll run a queue processor as a daemon, import the model bits from Django if you're using those, and do the updates/inserts/etc as you need.

The documentation includes [an example of processing a serial task](http://ask.github.com/celery/cookbook/tasks.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) that you can use as a template.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) with [RabbitMQ](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/broker-installation.html) or another [ghetto queue](http://ask.github.com/celery/tutorials/otherqueues.html).